# php curl super long url malformed

Tags: php, curl, malformed

I have a long url nested in a variable: $mp4, and trying to download it with curl but i'm getting malformed error. Please help me if you can, thank you in advance!

The below is what I have in my php script:

```
exec("curl -o $fnctid.mp4 \"$mp4\"");
```

Error message:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

Sample url to test download:

```
http://f26.stream.nixcdn.com/6f4df1d8c248cf149b846c24d32f1c35/514e0209/PreNCT5/22-TaylorSwift-2426783.mp4
```

Comment: What does the resulting command look like if you replace the variables? e.g. `echo '<pre>'; echo "curl -o $fnctid.mp4 \"$mp4\""; echo '</pre>';`. Also, you are aware that PHP offers support for curl without having to use the exec/command line: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: it actually works if I put in the url in their, but doesn't when I'm using variables instead...

Comment: Try it this way: `exec("curl -o " . $fnctid" . ".mp4 \"" . $mp4 . "\"");` I suspect that the problem lies in the `.` directly after the variable inside the string

Comment: I tried putting the that into a variable as well, still doesn't work....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current url is returning `408 - Request Timeout` if that is fixed you are you this simple code :

```
$url = 'http://f26.stream.nixcdn.com/6f4df1d8c248cf149b846c24d32f1c35/514e0209/PreNCT5/22-TaylorSwift-2426783.mp4';
$useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';


$file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($url);
$fp = fopen($file, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 320);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
echo curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));   // return request information 


curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! However, my old method also works today because I just realized that I had whitespaces in the url.

Answer (score 1):

This error  can be resolved through using urlencode

```
 $url = urlencode ( $url )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables.

Hope this solve answer

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work either... sample url: http://f26.stream.nixcdn.com/6f4df1d8c248cf149b846c24d32f1c35/514e0209/PreNCT5/22-TaylorSwift-2426783.mp4

Comment: Hm, based on the name of that URL, this seems to be a 'stream', not a regular file. You may not be able to download that!

Comment: than how come if I wget or curl it directly from shell then it works just fine?

Comment: hm, no idea then, not sure I'm able to help you further

Comment: That's very unfortunate, I was looking forward to get this under my belt. Thanks anyway.