# file_put_contents & file_get_contents damages my image

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents

The code is trivial;

```
$url = 'https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/417959_454038631356352_2061694564_n.jpg';
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
```

This results in the following image being written;

[image]

Note how it is "damaged" compared to [the original](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/417959_454038631356352_2061694564_n.jpg).

This is a new PHP installation on my Windows 8 Dev machine. My extensions are enabled as follows;

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_phar.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_zip.dll
```

Of note, I've enabled `openssl` for HTTPs support, and `curl`. `allow_url_fopen` is enabled (although of course, it wouldn't have got even this far if this wasn't the case).

Does anyone know what can cause this sort of damage to my images?

Comment: It might be a cache issue .. clear cache .. delete tem files .. then try again  after a simple restart

Comment: @Baba: Thanks. I've restarted but the issue remains :(.

Comment: Ok try using `CURLOPT_FILE` [see example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15636697/1226894)

Comment: @Baba: I've tried that, and still get exactly the same distortion (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5921268). `curl_error` shows nothing (empty string).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my Windows 8 Dev machine + ZendServer 6 PHP 5.4.11

Probably You have some problems in Your PHP instalation/configuration. I recommend reinstall PHP.